# Performance of clearing Sort-/GroupDescriptions on ICollectionView

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, sorting, grouping

After profiling an application I found that clearing an `ICollectionView`'s `GroupDescriptions` or `SortDescriptions` collection is incredibly expensive, and I don't see why that would be. It just doesn't seem to make much sense that clearing seems to be a lot more time consuming than applying a group- or sortdescription.

To further investigate, I used a stopwatch and found that for 1000 items, clearing a group description took as long as ~300ms while adding a new group description took ~30ms. I also tried to defer refreshing the view while replacing the group descriptions (i.e. removing the old, adding a new one), but that did not change anything. The individual add/remove calls returned immediately, but the refresh took as long as without deferring it.

I also observed that without a group description active, sorting behaves as expected, i.e. clearing and sorting are a few ms each, clearing being notably faster. With a group description applied, clearing the sort description (~1000ms) takes three times as long as applying a new one (~300ms). Apart from that being horrible performance in general, I just don't see where the complexity explodes here, especially for clearing.

So, I'd greatly appreciate if someone could explain this behaviour to me. Also, if you have an idea how to speed things up, please share.

Comment: Can you show us your demo please. There is so much you could do wrong with ICollectionView. Let us see how you are using it.

Comment: Grouping disables UI virtualization => all items will be rendered internally even when they are not visible. If you use .NET Framework 4.5 try setting VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping to true

Comment: @pindumb I tried the grouping virtualization setting, and it had no notable influence on the performance. Whipping up a demo might take a while, I'll try though

Comment: @pindumb Disregard my previous statement- I had a small mistake elsewhere. Bottom line, enabling virtualization when grouping actually caused an incredible performance gain! Add your comment as an answer and I'll be happy to accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by pindumb in the comments, the performance drop stems from grouping which by default disables virtualization (i.e., virtualization is enabled by default but dropped once you group the data). Simply adding `VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"`[[msdn]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingpanel.isvirtualizingwhengrouping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (available since .NET 4.5) to the e.g. ListBox that displays the data and the performance behaves as expected.